# selenium парсинг гифки вк

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Привет всем помогите плиз спарсить значение тега href, либо data-doc... нужно именно спарсить с помощью силениума+питон(что бы парсить и в закрытых группах ) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как пробовали?

Comment: через bs4 но в группах удаленные записи из-за этого криво парсить, так что нужен именно силениум.

Comment: Перефразирую. Где в вопросе код который не работает как Вам нужно?